# Making NFT with ERC-1155 standard

Tags: nft

I saw I can make NFTs with ERC-1155 standard but can I make more NFTs after selling them? The NFTs value comes from its limited count but if this possible, it means we can manipulate the value of the token.

Answer (score 0):

There's usually a limit on the number of NFTs you can mint for that particular contract. If this is not set, yes you can mint as many NFT's as you want and thus can manipulate the total supply.

There's a very interesting function in the Bored Ape's contract that allows a single wallet to mint unlimited new apes, check it out [here](https://cryptoslate.com/bayc-smart-contract-function-allows-unlimited-minting-of-new-apes-by-single-wallet/).

So yes you can manipulate the total supply of these tokens,but if you have such functions in your contract, people will pick that up and may never buy your NFT's in the first place

Comment: So is it possible to manipulate the NFT count by adding more contract?

Comment: If there exists a function in the contract with which you can mint more NFT's, yes you can manipulate the NFT count